# How I calculate the volume of multiple intersecting spheres?

Tags: graphics3d

I would like to know how to calculate the volume of the union of multiple possibly intersecting spheres (using Sphere[]). Please see the figure:

[image]

I was trying to get a mesh/delaunayMesh out of the spheres and apply "Volume" which didn't work.

Edit: Fixed spelling (Feb 6th).

Comment: Please include any code you have developed to try to solve this problem.  Also, please reformat your code you have displayed according to the guidelines in [meta1027](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1027/what-kind-of-input-and-output-code-styles-are-acceptable-in-se). Doing so will encourage more people to consider your question.

Comment: Do you want the volume of the intersection of the spheres, or the volume of the union of the spheres (which happen to be intersecting)?

Comment: The volume of the union of the spheres.

Comment: Most of the solutions posted here work fine for 2 to 4 nodes (spheres). But any number of spheres which is higher brings up the following message:`RegionMeasure::nmet: Unable to compute the measure of region RegionUnion[Ball[{100.,100.,100.},30.],Ball[{120.,120.,120.},30.],Ball[{130.,130.,130.},30.],Ball[{140.,140.,140.},30.],<<1>>,<<1>>,Ball[{190.,190.,190.},30.],Ball[{200.,200.,200.},30.],Ball[{210.,210.,210.},30.],Ball[{230.,230.,230.},30.]]. >>` Any idea what it could be?

Comment: `NIntegrate` might be better for many spheres. you might want to provide a real example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
spheres = {
   Sphere[{50, 50, 50}, 25],
   Sphere[{70, 70, 70}, 25]};

rgn = RegionUnion @@
   (spheres /. Sphere -> Ball);

RegionMeasure[rgn // N]
```

> 122585.

```
Volume[rgn // N]
```

> 122585.

EDIT: Example with more elements

```
rgn2 = RegionUnion[
   Ball[{100., 100., 100.}, 30.], Ball[{120., 120., 120.}, 30.], 
   Ball[{130., 130., 130.}, 30.], Ball[{140., 140., 140.}, 30.], 
   Ball[{190., 190., 190.}, 30.], Ball[{200., 200., 200.}, 30.], 
   Ball[{210., 210., 210.}, 30.], Ball[{230., 230., 230.}, 30.]];

RegionMeasure[rgn2]
```

> 590768.

```
Volume[rgn2]
```

> 590768.

Comment: This helped me! The calculation is fast and I can extend the solution to multiple spheres. Many thanks!

Comment: Again, thank you, this helped me. It works nicely for up to 4 to 5 randomly distributed spheres. But any number of spheres which is higher brings up the following message:`RegionMeasure::nmet: Unable to compute the measure of region RegionUnion[Ball[{100.,100.,100.},30.],Ball[{120.,120.,120.},30.],Ball[{130.,130.,130.},30.],Ball[{140.,140.,140.},30.],<<1>>,<<1>>,Ball[{190.,190.,190.},30.],Ball[{200.,200.,200.},30.],Ball[{210.,210.,210.},30.],Ball[{230.,230.,230.},30.]]. >>` Any idea what it could be? I have this problem also for two more solution proposed here.

Comment: Example above with eight balls worked without a problem.

Comment: Bob, yes, it worked for me too. I included more two balls and it didn't work anymore. Same error. I think it must be my system. Does it work for you with 10? `rgn2 = RegionUnion[Ball[{100., 100., 100.}, 30.], 
   Ball[{120., 120., 120.}, 30.], Ball[{130., 130., 130.}, 30.], 
   Ball[{140., 140., 140.}, 30.], Ball[{190., 190., 190.}, 30.], 
   Ball[{200., 200., 200.}, 30.], Ball[{210., 210., 210.}, 30.], 
   Ball[{230., 230., 230.}, 30.],
   Ball[{135., 130., 130.}, 30.], Ball[{140., 140., 140.}, 30.], 
   Ball[{195., 190., 190.}, 30.], Ball[{200., 200., 200.}, 30.]];

RegionMeasure[rgn2]`

Comment: Neither `RegionMeasure` nor `Volume` worked for nine or more `Ball`s on my system. Perhaps the level of complexity causes the calculation to exceed some time limit. You might try subdividing the region, sum the volume of the subregions, and subtract the intersections of the subregions.

Comment: I agree. Anyhow, your solution helped me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Let the spheres have radius $r1$ and $r2$ and their centers be separated by distance $d$.  There are four cases:

- $r1+r2 < d$ (separate spheres):  $V = {4 \pi \over 3} (r1^3 + r2^3)$
- $r1 > r2 \wedge d + r2 < r1$ (sphere 2 within sphere 1):  $V = {4 \pi \over 3} r1^3$
- $r2 > r1 \wedge d + r1 < r2$ (sphere 1 within sphere 2):  $V = {4 \pi \over 3} r2^3$
- $r1 + r2 <d \wedge (d + r2 > r1 \vee d + r1 > r2)$ (partially intersecting spheres): $V = {4 \pi \over 3}(r1^3 + r2^3) - V_{cap1} - V_{cap2}$ (see below).

This last result comes from realizing that when two spheres partially intersect, we can define a plane through the circle defined by the spheres' intersecting surfaces.  Then there are two "caps" that are "overcounted":  the "cap" of sphere 1 within sphere 2, and the "cap" of sphere 2 within sphere 1.  The cap of sphere 1 within sphere 2 has volume

$V_{cap1} = \int_{h1}^r \pi r^2(x) dx$ ,

where

$r^2(x) = r1^2 - x^2$.

Thus $V_{cap1} = \frac{1}{3} \pi  (\text{h1}-\text{r1})^2 (\text{h1}+2 \text{r1})$.

Likewise, we have

$V_{cap2} = \frac{\pi  (d-\text{h1}+2 \text{r2}) \left(d^2-2 d \text{r2}+\text{r1}^2-\text{r2}^2\right)^2}{12 d^2}$.

Here $h1$ is the distance from sphere 1's center to the plane, and likewise for sphere 2.  Note that here $h1 + h2 = d$.  We solve for $h1$ by $\sqrt{r1^2 - h1^2} = \sqrt{r2^2 - (d - h1)^2}$ then the total volume is the sum of the volumes of the individual spheres (${4 \pi \over 3}ri^3$) minus the two overcounted "caps" given by $h1$ and $h2 = d - h1$.

[image]

Of course this computes lightning fast.

Comment: the analytic approach should be preferred ( for only two spheres in any case). You ought to post the mathematica code though..

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately as of 10.0.2, `RegionIntersection` is not implemented for `MeshRegion` nor `BoundaryMeshRegion` objects embedded in 3D. But you could use `ImplicitRegion[]` as follows:

```
r1 = ImplicitRegion[(x - 50)^2 + (y - 50)^2 + (z - 50)^2 <= 25^2, {x, 
    y, z}];
r2 = ImplicitRegion[(x - 70)^2 + (y - 70)^2 + (z - 70)^2 <= 25^2, {x, 
    y, z}];
Volume[RegionIntersection[r1, r2]]
RegionPlot3D[{r1, r2}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

Comment: Note that calls to `Volume[]` can sometimes take a long time!

Comment: I run the code. It really took long. :-(  At the end, I got the following message: Unable to compute the volume of region. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
ball[{x0_, y0_, z0_}, r_] := (x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 + (z - z0)^2 <= r^2.;
region = ImplicitRegion[ball[{50, 50, 50}, 25] && ball[{75, 75, 75}, 25], {x, y, z}];
Volume[region]

(*1683.46*)
```

Comment: `ball[{x0_, y0_, z0_}, r_] := (x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 + (z - z0)^2 <= 
   r^2.;
region = ImplicitRegion[
   ball[{50, 50, 50}, 25] && ball[{75, 75, 75}, 10], {x, y, z}];
Volume[region]` (* 0 *) which is incorrect.  You probably want `NAND`.

Comment: There is no intersection in your case. OP asked for the intersection not the union.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NIntegrate[ 
       Boole[  
            Norm[ {x, y, z}  - {50, 50, 50}] < 25 || 
            Norm[ {x, y, z}  - {70, 70, 70}] < 25  ] , 
               {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}, {z, 0, 100}] // Chop
```

> 122585.